# Why is child component re-rendering if only prop has useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

Child component only is supposed to re-render if its prop (numberModifier) is modified.
numberModifier is using useCallback with no dependencies. Thus, it never changes.

In order to test this, I modify the value of “online” (inside Application) which happens to be the prop of Parent so both Application and Parent are re-rendered when “online” is modified.

That makes sense.

However, Child is also re-rendered. I don’t understand why this is happening. It’s only prop (numberModifier) is not modified.

**Why is Child re-rendering when I modify the value of online (Application)?**

If that’s the correct behaviour, what’s the point of using useCallback?

```
function Application() {
 const [online, setOnline] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={()=>setOnline(!online)}>Change Flag</button>
    <Parent online={online}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function Parent({online}) {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const numberModifier = useCallback(()=> {
    setNumber(69)
  },[])

  return (
    <>
    <p>Online is {online.toString()}</p>
    <p>Number is {number}</p>
    <Child numberModifier={numberModifier} />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
function Child({ numberModifier }) {
    return (
        <button onClick={numberModifier}>modify</button>
    );
}
```

This is a screenshot taken from profiler. That shows that Child is re-rendered because its parent was re-rendered.
Note: Child is the green bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so when if there's somethig changes in states in parent component, all the child components are re-rendered except you wrap your Child component using React.memo(Child).

```
const [online, setOnline] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={()=>setOnline(!online)}>Change Flag</button>
    <Parent online={online}/>
    </div>
  );
```

when `online` states has been changed,
all the child components re rendered, in this case your `<Parent online={online}/>`

because your Parent get props `online`, whole nested component inside your `Parent` will be re-rendered no matter you wrap `numberModifier` with `useCallback`.

If you want to prevent your `Child` Component re-render, wrap your `Child` Component with `React.memo()`

Comment: If that´s the case, what´s the benefit of using useCallback?

Comment: if function props is not wrapped with useCallback, whether you use React.memo or not, your Child Component will be re rendered. because numberModifier will be create every re render in Parent Component